# My first multi-file C++ Program Keeps Giving Me Error Messages

Tags: c++, file, function, scope

Add.cpp

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is: " << add(3, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this program I get an error message for line 6 of main.cpp that states: "error: 'add' was not declared in this scope".

Comment: And how exactly are you including add.cpp?

Comment: Add a third file `Add.hpp` containing `int add(int x, int y);`, and `#include "Add.hpp"` in both `Add.cpp` and `Main.cpp`.

Comment: Note that you CAN include .cpp files but you shouldn't because it will insert duplicate definitions of the function in every file its included in

Answer (score 1):

Create a header file

Contents:

```
    int add(int x, y);
```

Include that file main.cpp

i.e. #include "headerfile.h"

Then the rest is up to the compiler environment. Basically need to compile each .cpp to object code and then link them. You need to read up about this as this differs between environment. Also read up on header guards and also stuff like graadle, SCONS, Makefiles. Also good to learn about version control systes e.g. mercurial.

Guess you going to have a busy day

Answer (score 0):

You need `Add.h` file and include it in your `Main.cpp`

**Add.h**

```
int add(int x, int y);
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Add.h"

...
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++ the scope is all visible functions/methods and variables. In order for it to be seen in the scope in this instance you would have to create a header file that contains your method "add". One way to do this would be to instead of having it in a .cpp file have it in a .h file, then include that .h file in your main.cpp file like this

```
#include "Add.h"
```

Comment: Putting the definition inside of a header as-is is a bad idea due to the One Definition Rule.

Comment: I understand this, but this is the guys first multi-file C++ project so I figured keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed the headers and it all seems fine now. The only problem is that on line 6 of main.cpp, I get the errors "multiple definitions of 'main'", and on line 5 "first defined here" (I'm guessing this must also relate to main. What should I do about this? Thanks in advance, you guys have all been great.